# how to use relationship after decoding json in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i have an application that needs multicategory to one product and i make it using `json_encode` and after i decoded it it must now show me the id of each category so i tried to use relationships to solve that but know relationships is igroned and says to me No Category exsist on collection
and here is the code
Controller

```
    public function index()
{
    $data = Product::all();
    $attribute = Attribute::all();
    $settings = Setting::all()->first();
    return view('admin.products.index',['data'=>$data,'setting'=>$settings,'attribute'=>$attribute]);
}
```

my view

```
   @foreach ( $data as $product )
                    <tr style="overflow:hidden; max-hieght:300px;">
                        <td>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($product->title_en, 50, '...') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ \Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($product->title_srb, 50, '...') }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <?php foreach (json_decode($product->category_id)as $cat) { ?>
                                {{ $cat->Category }}
                            <?php } ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><img src="{{ asset('product-imgs/thumbnail/').'/'.$product->thumb }}" alt="failed to load thumbnail image {{ $product->title }}" width="100" style="height:100px;"></td>
                        <td>
                            @if(!empty($product->price))
                                PPMC: {{ $product->price }} RSD
                                @else
                                <span style="color: #444">@if(App::getLocale() == 'en')RRP: @elseif(App::getLocale() == 'srb')PPMC: @endif </span><span class="new_price">  @foreach ($product->attributes->sortBy('price')->slice(0, 1) as $option) {{ $option->price }} @endforeach - @foreach ($product->attributes->sortByDesc('price')->slice(0, 1) as $option)     {{ $option->price }} @endforeach RSD</span>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($product->in_stock == 1)
                                Yes
                            @elseif($product->in_stock == 0)
                                No
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($product->is_featured == 1)
                                Yes
                            @elseif($product->is_featured == 0)
                                No <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('admin/product/'.$product->id.'/featured') }}">set as popular featured</a>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($product->featured == 1)
                                Yes it is featured <p class="text-danger"><a href="{{ url('admin/product/'.$product->id.'/remove_f') }}">remove</a></p>
                            @elseif($product->is_featured == 0)
                                No <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url('admin/product/'.$product->id.'/features') }}">set as featured</a>
                            @endif
                        </td>
                        @if ($product->attributes != NULL)
                        <td>
                            <a href="attribute/{{ $product->id }}" style="color: blue;" target="_blank">Attributes</a>
                        </td>
                        @endif
                       
                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete??')" href="{{ url('admin/product/'.$product->id.'/delete') }}">delete</a></td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{url('admin/product'.'/'.$product->id.'/edit')}}">edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
```

like now how i can make relation ships in my model also i tried to use a laravel package but i failed this package called eloquent-relation-ships

MODEl OF PRODUCT:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = ['object' => 'array'];

    public function Category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category_id');
    }
    function Subcategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Subcategory','sub_category_id');
    }
    function Attributes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attribute');
    }
```

i hope anyone find solution! :D